# Debugging vscode front-end and back-end in studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have the same application and debug client-side parts in the visual studio code and server-side parts in the visual studio? ASP.NET Core in particular

Comment: What web browser are you using? Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Safari, Opera, Brave, other?

Comment: Mainly Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out by myself, so if anyone's wondering this is what you have to do:
**VScode** launch url should be the same as is on the visual studio, you should open client side project or wherever your files are. Vs should run on IIS server, that way you wont need to debug in visual studio in case you don't like debugging in chrome.